# Não consigo salvar as informações em um banco de dados local!

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou tendo problemas para salvar as informações digitadas pelo usuário no banco de dados PostgreSQL, desenvolvi uma aplicação no Android Studio e estou utilizando um banco de dados externo local com o PostgreSQL para guardar os dados, porém quando executo a aplicação e insiro os dados a aplicação para de funcionar, já olhei o código e não consigui achar o erro na função.

### Stack Trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.matheus.privatewalletm, PID: 3423
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format java.lang.String arguments
at java.util.Formatter.badArgumentType(Formatter.java:1489)
at java.util.Formatter.transformFromInteger(Formatter.java:1689)
at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1461)
at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1803)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1777)
at com.example.matheus.privatewalletm.Usuario.confirmar(Usuario.java:134)
at com.example.matheus.privatewalletm.Novo.confirmar(Novo.java:61)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

### Classes Envolvidas

Classe `Novo`:

```
public class Novo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Usuario usuario;
    private EditText editTextNome;
    private EditText editTextData;
    private EditText editTextRg;
    private EditText editTextCpf;
    private EditText editTextDoenca;
    private EditText editTextAlergia;
    private EditText editTextProfissao;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_novo);

        this.usuario = new Usuario();
        this.editTextNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
        this.editTextData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
        this.editTextRg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRg);
        this.editTextCpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCpf);
        this.editTextDoenca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDoenca);
        this.editTextAlergia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAlergia);
        this.editTextProfissao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProfissao);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
            if(intent != null){
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if(bundle != null){
                    this.usuario.setId(bundle.getInt("id"));
                    this.editTextNome.setText(bundle.getString("nome"));
                    this.editTextData.setText(bundle.getInt("data"));
                    this.editTextRg.setText(bundle.getString("rg"));
                    this.editTextCpf.setText(bundle.getString("cpf"));
                    this.editTextDoenca.setText(bundle.getString("doenca"));
                    this.editTextAlergia.setText(bundle.getString("alergia"));
                    this.editTextProfissao.setText(bundle.getString("profissao"));

                }
            }
    }

    public void confirmar (View view){
        this.usuario.setNome(this.editTextNome.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setData(this.editTextData.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setRg(this.editTextRg.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setCpf(this.editTextCpf.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setDoenca(this.editTextDoenca.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setAlergia(this.editTextAlergia.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setProfissao(this.editTextProfissao.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.confirmar();

        Toast.makeText(this,this.usuario.get_messagem(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(usuario._status)
            finish();
    }

    public void cancelar (View view){
        finish();
    }
}
```

Classe `Usuario`:

```
public class Usuario extends _default {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String data;
    private String rg;
    private String cpf;
    private String doenca;
    private String alergia;
    private String profissao;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getDoenca() {
        return doenca;
    }

    public void setDoenca(String doenca) {
        this.doenca = doenca;
    }

    public String getAlergia() {
        return alergia;
    }

    public void setAlergia(String alergia) {
        this.alergia = alergia;
    }

    public String getProfissao() {
        return profissao;
    }

    public void setProfissao(String profissao) {
        this.profissao = profissao;
    }

    public Usuario(){
        super();
        this.id = -1;
        this.nome = "";
        this.data = "";
        this.rg = "";
        this.cpf = "";

        this.doenca = "";
        this.alergia = "";
        this.profissao = "";
    }

    public ArrayList<Usuario> getLista(){
        BD bd = new BD();
        ArrayList<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = bd.select("SELECT * FROM usuario");
            if(resultSet != null ){
                while (resultSet.next()){
                    Usuario obj = new Usuario();
                    obj.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    obj.setNome(resultSet.getString("nome"));
                    obj.setData(resultSet.getString("data"));
                    obj.setRg(resultSet.getString("rg"));
                    obj.setCpf(resultSet.getString("cpf"));
                    obj.setDoenca(resultSet.getString("doenca"));
                    obj.setAlergia(resultSet.getString("alergia"));
                    obj.setProfissao(resultSet.getString("profissao"));
                    lista.add(obj);
                    obj = null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
            this._status = false;

        }
        return lista;
    }

    public void confirmar(){
        String comando = "";
        if(this.getId() == -1){
            comando = String.format("INSERT INTO Usuario(nome, data, rg, cpf, doenca, alergia, profissao) values ('%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s' );",
                    this.getNome(), this.getData(), this.getRg(), this.getCpf(), this.getDoenca(), this.getAlergia(), this.getProfissao());

        }
        else
        {
            comando = String.format("UPDATE Usuario SET nome ='%s', date = '%d', rg = '%s', cpf = '%s', doenca = '%s', alergia = '%s', profissao = '%s' WHERE id = %d;",
                    this.getNome(), this.getData(), this.getRg(), this.getCpf(), this.getDoenca(), this.getAlergia(), this.getProfissao(), this.getId());
        }
        BD bd = new BD();
       bd.execute(comando);
       this._messagem = bd._messagem;
        this._status = bd._status ;
    }

    public void apagar(){
        String  comando =  String.format("DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id = %d ", this.getId());

        BD bd = new BD();
        bd.execute(comando);
        this._messagem = bd._messagem;
        this._status = bd._status ;    
    }    
}
```

Classe `UsuarioAdapter`:

```
public class UsuarioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Usuario> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Usuario> lista;

public UsuarioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Usuario> lista)
    {
        super(context,0,lista);
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final Usuario itemPosicao = this.lista.get(position);

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.item_lista,null);
        final View layout = convertView;

        TextView textViewNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
        textViewNome.setText(itemPosicao.getNome());

        TextView textViewData = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
        textViewData.setText(itemPosicao.getData());

        TextView textViewRg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRg);
        textViewRg.setText(itemPosicao.getRg());

        TextView textViewCpf = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCpf);
        textViewCpf.setText(itemPosicao.getCpf());

        TextView textViewDoenca = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDoenca);
        textViewDoenca.setText(itemPosicao.getDoenca());

        TextView textViewAlergia = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAlergia);
        textViewAlergia.setText(itemPosicao.getAlergia());

        TextView textViewProfissao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfissao);
        textViewProfissao.setText(itemPosicao.getProfissao());

        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEditar);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Novo.class);
            intent.putExtra("nome", itemPosicao.getNome());
            intent.putExtra("data", itemPosicao.getData());
            intent.putExtra("rg", itemPosicao.getRg());
            intent.putExtra("cpf", itemPosicao.getCpf());
            intent.putExtra("doenca", itemPosicao.getDoenca());
            intent.putExtra("alergia", itemPosicao.getAlergia());
            intent.putExtra("profissao", itemPosicao.getProfissao());
            context.startActivity(intent);
           }
        });
    Button buttonDeletar = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonApagar);
        buttonDeletar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemPosicao.apagar();
                if (itemPosicao._status)
                    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(context, itemPosicao.get_messagem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            });

        return convertView;  
    }
}
```

### Classes do BD

Classe `ExecuteBD`:

```
public class ExecuteBD extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ResultSet>{
    private Connection connection;
    private String query;

    public ExecuteBD(Connection connection, String query) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.query = query;
    }


    @Override
    protected ResultSet doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try
        {
            resultSet = connection.prepareStatement(query).executeQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());

        }finally {
            try
            {
            connection.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Classe `BD`:

```
public class BD extends _default implements Runnable {
    private Connection conn;
    private String host = "192.168.0.100";
    private String db = "android";
    private int port = 2345;
    private String user = "androidUser";
    private String pass = "*android*";
    private String url = "jbdc:postgresql://%s:%d/%s";

    public BD (){
        super();
        this.url = String.format(this.url, this.host, this.port, this.db);

        this.conecta();
        this.disconecta();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.pass);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
            this._status = false;

        }
    }
    private void conecta(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        try
        {
            thread.join();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
            this._status = false;
        }
    }

    private void disconecta(){
        if(this.conn != null ){
            try
            {
                this.conn.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            }finally {
                this.conn = null;
            }
        }
    }
    public ResultSet select (String query){
        this.conecta();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            resultSet = new ExecuteBD(this.conn, query).execute().get();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._status = false;
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
        }
        return resultSet;
    }

    public ResultSet execute (String query){
        this.conecta();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            resultSet = new ExecuteBD(this.conn, query).execute().get();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._status = false;
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Imagem da tabela do BD:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No erro, existe um momento que ele faz referência que a causa do erro é em uma conversão... nesta aqui: `comando = String.format("INSERT INTO Usuario(nome, data, rg, cpf, doenca, alergia, profissao) values ('%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s' );",
                    this.getNome(), this.getData(), this.getRg(), this.getCpf(), this.getDoenca(), this.getAlergia(), this.getProfissao());`... está tentando passar uma  String no lugar de um inteiro.

Comment: Aqui `%d`, não seria `%s`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: `%d` can't format java.lang.String arguments

No método `confirmar`, na classe `Usuario`, ao usar o [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) você está usando o formato `%d` para a função `getData` que retorna uma *string*:

```
public class Usuario extends _default {
    // ...
    private String data;
    // ...

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
```

Isso acontece em ambas as linhas do `if/else`:

```
public void confirmar(){
    String comando = "";
    if(this.getId() == -1){
        comando = String.format(
          "INSERT INTO Usuario(nome, data, ...) values ('%s', '%d', ....);",
          this.getNome(), this.getData(), ...);                ^^
    }
    else
    {
        comando = String.format(
          "UPDATE Usuario SET nome ='%s', date = '%d', ...",
          this.getNome(), this.getData(), ...);   ^^
    }
    // ....
}
```

Altere `%d` para `%s`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, pela ajuda, porem agora o programa roda como se cadastra-se a informação, mas não cria ela no BD nem exibe na lista, já revisei o código e esta tudo certo, será q o problema agora está no BD e não no código de cadastro ???

Comment: Bom eu testei, e ele aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:  0 D/PrivateWalletM: ERROR: relation "usuario" does not exist
                                                                                      Position: 13

Comment: Sim ela é a tabela onde eu vou salvar os dados do aplicativo. No final da minha pergunta eu coloquei uma imagem dela pra mostrar como ela está criada

Comment: Nao entendi... onde eu deveria trocar para "Usuario", pq ali onde está usuario é apenas um objeto da classe Usuario, então não teria problema quando fosse salvar eu acho. Então onde eu deveria passar a chamar de Usuario???

Comment: Quando eu executo o programa ele não mostra erro nenhum no código, só executa com se tivesse correto, mas não cadastra no banco e nem mostra nada

Comment: Já fiz isso... Mas não trás nada do meu bd

Comment: nada mudou, o msm erro continua lá: ERROR: relation "usuario" does not exist
                                                                                      Position: 15

Comment: Bom trocando o nome da tabela para "usuario", ele ainda não cadastra no BD, mas agora exibe o seguinte erro:

Comment: Fiz a troca em tudo, e acontece a msm coisa, o novo erro foi corrigido, a aplicação não para, mas voltou a estaca 0, não cadastra no BD nem exibe nada...

Comment: Eu debbuguei tudo, e o único erro q apareceu foi esse: ERROR: permission denied for relation usuario, porem não sei como resolve-lo também.